# Work it takes to move a charge from one point to another closer to an infinite uniformly charged plate?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

[image]

In the video, (khan) says to calculate the work done on the charge to move it from a point to 3 meters closer to the plane, you multiply it by the force at the original point by the distance (3 meters).

I understand it from the work-force equation, but as you move a charge closer, doesn't the electric field and force from the plate on the charge get stronger/change? How does that factor in?

Comment: The assumption is that the charge is a "probe charge". This means that we neglect any effects the charge has on the other fields and sources, which we then assume as a fixed background.

Answer (score 2):

For an infinitely large charge plane, electric field at regions closer to the plane can be considered constant for calculations.

To find this electric field, Gauss' law is typically used. Depending on the charge distribution we can have two different values of electric field. If the plate is very thin, you only have a single sheet of uniform charge distribution but if the plate is thicker you have two sheets of uniformly distributed charge on either side of the plate.

To use Gauss law, it should be easy to find electric flux and for an infinite plane the electric field line are almost perfectly straight for regions closer to the plane. This makes our task a lot easier.

For a thin charged sheet electric field is given as shown.

[image]

Through the proper way of integration for a thin charged disk (axis parallel to x-axis) we arrive at the same result as long as the distance between the particle and the plate is small.

$$E_{x}=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon _{\circ}}(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{R^2}{x^2}}}),E_{y}=0$$

But for our case, $R\rightarrow \infty$ and $x\rightarrow 0$

$\therefore E_{x}=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon _{\circ}}$